# How to POST data from this.state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to use `this.state` in a POST call with Axios, and I can't understand why it isn't working. I tried to connect (getting a "bind () is not a function" error) and setState, but nothing seems to work . I can't find any good solution for this problem, follow the code below, thanks for your help in advance!

````
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class AccountSettings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            projects: "Loading...",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/../api/****/account/projects")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        projects: result
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    saveProjects(event) {
        axios.post('/../api/****/account/projects/save',{
            projects: this.state.projects,
        })
            .then()
            .catch();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleOnChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            projects: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form method="post" onSubmit={this.saveProjects}>
                <label htmlFor="projectsInput">My projects</label>
                <textarea className="form-control" id="projectsInput" rows="3" aria-describedby="projectsInputHelp"
    name="projectsInput" value={this.state.projects}
                          onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)} />

                <small id="projectsInputHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                    Add every project on a new line.<br/><br/>
                </small>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Save projects
                </button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AccountSettings />, document.getElementById("account-settings"));```
````

Comment: You didn't ask a question. You might think the question is obvious, but you should clarify more what you want to happen, and what went wrong instead. You also probably should remove some irrelevant code, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding works for me `this.saveProjects=this.saveProjects.bind(this);` and if somehow binding fails then you can always use arrow functions in class components.

Comment: Thanks! This way the solution, I binded the wrong function...

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this:

```
let data = Object.keys(this.state.fields).map(key => encodeURIComponent('formName['+key+']') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.fields[key])).join('&'))


fetch('....', {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' <--- if needed for php framework isXmlHTTPRequest()
        }
      })
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( json => {
          console.log(json);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```